How to make a heterostructure
I have two hexagonal structures with lattice parameters 3.425 and 3.14. I try supercell or sqrt3 method but lattice mismatch does not reduced. Is there in way to make a heterostructure from these lattice parameters. Any suggestion is highly appreciated.
Also, after making a heterostructure do we have to do again lattice optimization and relaxation?

I dont know what methods you are talking about, but what I have done in the past for e.g. Si/Ge superlattice is change lattice constants of Si to that of Ge so that the structures match perfectly, then I relax the structure to incorporate the strain. Keep in mind that, in some real heterostructures made in the lab, there will be defects since the lattices dont line up.  So any DFT method without defects is just an approximation. I suggest finding papers and seeing what others have done before and trying to understand why they did things the way they did.

@Tyler Sterling my question is that the lattice mismatch between lattice parameters is around 9% in my case so how can i reduce it. Should i simply take the average and than optimize the lattice parameter of heterostructure?

That sounds like a reasonable idea. Or you can see what is done in the literature.
